# How to split the polygon, operation using of JSTS?

Tags: javascript, polygon, openlayers, splitting

I'm use JSTS 0.17.0 (https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts).
How to split the polygon (polygon to multipolygon or two polygons) ?

[image]

Input:

- `POLYGON ((1 1, 1 9, 9 9, 9 1, 1 1))`
- `LINESTRING (0.5 5, 9.6 5, 9.6 3.9)`

Result (or):

- `MULTIPOLYGON (((9 5, 9 1, 1 1, 1 5, 9 5)),((9 9, 9 5, 1 5, 1 9, 9 9)))`
- `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ( POLYGON ((9 5, 9 1, 1 1, 1 5, 9 5)), POLYGON ((9 9, 9 5, 1 5, 1 9, 9 9)) )`

JTS does so:

[image]

How do too JSTS ?

***PS2***
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Do you mean this library https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts?

Comment: Yes, it library.

Comment: @t1nk do you have any feedback upon my answer?

Comment: Where did you get that GUI interface?

Comment: I figured it out. Its included with the JTS github code. You have to build the project using maven and then run testbuilder.bat.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
// Output:
// POLYGON((1 1,1 5,9 5,9 1,1 1))
// POLYGON((1 5,1 9,9 9,9 5,1 5))

var reader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
var writer = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();

var a = reader.read('POLYGON ((1 1, 1 9, 9 9, 9 1, 1 1))');
var b = reader.read('LINESTRING (0.5 5, 9.6 5, 9.6 3.9)');
var union = a.getExteriorRing().union(b);

var polygonizer = new jsts.operation.polygonize.Polygonizer();
polygonizer.add(union);

var polygons = polygonizer.getPolygons();
for (var i = polygons.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    var polygon = i.next();
    console.log(writer.write(polygon));
}
```

Comment: As a result, multipolygon is needed, and it is not valid: self-intersections :( For the separation of polygons - suit

Comment: In my answer I've got two simple valid polygons. What self-intersection do you mean? Or you have to split not only simple polygons as you pointed in your question?

Comment: The result coincides with that obtained in TestBuild, thank you. But I cut multipolygon, and the result will be a multipolygon. The geometry of the cut is perfect - there are no objections, but calculating it fall down because the validity check.